# Cloning Meson git subproject repositories from Docker?

Tags: docker, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, meson-build

My project is hosted on GitHub and uses Meson build system. The project heavily uses Meson's **subproject** feature: there is one top project repo which uses several "child" repositories. Child repos are cloned from the GitHub by Meson at the "setup" stage (see below).

I tried to build the project using Jenkins and Docker, but failed. The problem is the GitHub access from the Docker container.

Here is the Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline
{
    agent { label 'ag1' }
    stages
    {
      stage('testrun')
        {
            agent
            {
                dockerfile
                {
                    label "ag2"
                }
            }
            steps
            {
                sh "meson setup builddir"
                sh "meson compile -C builddir"
            }
```

The Jenkins test job works up to a point where Meson tries to fetch subproject repositories from GitHub: `meson setup builddir`. The error is `ERROR: Git command failed`.

How would I go about this problem? How could I allow Jenkins to access GitHub from the Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

Add this to the Jenkinsfile:

```
dockerfile
{
    args ('-v /home/jenkins/.ssh:/home/jenkins/.ssh')
    additionalBuildArgs ('--build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g)')    
}
```

The host machine needs to have SSH key installed for accessing GitHub, and this key needs to be shared with Docker container. That's what the `args` line does using the `-v` ([volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)) option.

The [additionalBuildArgs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) line sets the user `id` to be `jenkins`, and this also requires changes in the Dockerfile:

```
# Create a Jenkins user
ARG UNAME=jenkins
# Get group and user id from outside "additionalBuildArgs" 
ARG GID= 
ARG UID= 
# Add Jenkins user with proper host group id and user id
RUN groupadd --gid $GID $UNAME
RUN useradd --gid $GID --uid $UID --home-dir /home/$UNAME --create-home $UNAME
```

Now the `jenkins` user can access GitHub repositories and `meson` commands can be used.